# Nautilus bhaviour preferences in 22.04

Tags: scripts, nautilus, files, 22.04

What has happened to the Preferences-Behaviour settings in 22.04. Is there another way to set the behaviour of script files  when they are double clicked? There used to be that option in the nautilus menu in 20.04. The behaviour could also be modified in dconf-editor, but I don't see it there now either.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What precisely is unclear. Use "edit  and update your question to be a little bit more specific.

Comment: It's a little bit unclear, so please answer this comment to make your question more clear. In Ubuntu 22.04 select  Files -> Preferences -> General -> Double click  dropdown menu. Is this the menu that you are looking for in 22.04?

Comment: I'm sorry if I was unclear, and I don't know what I can add. In Files, I click on the menu, select preferences and under General I have three items: 'Sort folders before files', 'Expandable folders in list view' and 'Action to open items'. I do not see any menu, nor any 'Behaviour' (or 'Behavior'). There was an option in 20.04 to choose default behaviour: 'open', 'execute', or 'ask'. Is there something wrong with my installation?

Comment: Have the same problem. in Dconf-Editor, org.gnome.nautilus there is no such key as “executable-text-activation”, so it can't be set to 'launch'

Comment: So I believe this option has been withdrawn as a security flaw.